# Can you use a PowerShell command in scheduled task or do you have to use a file? | -command VS -file

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

The script is below. I realized that what I was doing wrong was to use `LOCALSERVICES` instead of `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` as the the User or Group. This gave me an `Operational Code (2)` and did not work in Task Scheduler.

```
PowerShell -command "Get-ChildItem C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ | Remove-Item"
```

Strangely, changing to SYSTEM still gave me the Op Code but the code worked.

On another note I'm irritated that the images I originally posted didn't show up on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as ([properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Answer (score 1):

You can use both, it depends on the requirements.

-FILE
If the value of File is "-", the command text is read from standard input. Running powershell -File - without redirected standard input starts a regular session. This is the same as not specifying the File parameter at all.

-COMMAND
Executes the specified commands (and any parameters) as though they were typed at the PowerShell command prompt, and then exits, unless the NoExit parameter is specified.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1